# Slow batch import with in-memory H2 database

Tags: hibernate, grails, h2

I have a domain class with five properties, all of which are either strings, integers, or doubles. I am using an H2 in-memory database as my datasource for this domain class. This is the only object stored in this database; the rest are stored in an entirely separate MySQL database.

The H2 database is temporary. Data is loaded from a remotely-downloaded CSV file every hour and replaces the old data in the database. Because all other processes must wait for it to finish, it's important that it is as fast as possible.

Right now my code generates an array of about 6,000 of these domain objects, then for each `save`s it. This is all inside a `withTransaction`.

This takes about 10 seconds to save. The numbers are slightly worse with an HSQLDB in-memory datasource. I've tried following instructions on flushing the session and such, but these only increase the time it takes.

What is the best solution to speed up the batch insert of these 6,000 objects? Would abandoning GORM and writing SQL insert statements directly be significantly faster?

```
// data is an array of about 6,000 domain objects
data.each { item ->
    item.save()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CSV import](http://h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#csv) is a very important use case. H2 has support for fast CSV import. Most likely this is faster than when using a tool.

You said "remotely-downloaded CSV file". Is it a temporary file? If yes, you could use the CSV import from a file. The fastest way is

```
CREATE TABLE TEST(ID INT PRIMARY KEY, NAME VARCHAR(255))
AS SELECT * FROM CSVREAD('test.csv');
```

This is faster than creating the table first and then insert. It is also faster than using batch insert.

If you don't have a file but only an input stream, you could use the CSV tool directly, using `new Csv().read(Reader r)`, and read the rows from there and insert them into the database.

Of course you can try to find out where the bottleneck is by profiling. You can use your own profiler, or the built-in profiler of H2. See also [Application Profiling](http://h2database.com/html/performance.html#application_profiling) in the H2 documentation.